# set array from MongoDB as a variable

Tags: arrays, mongodb, dictionary, pymongo

I am using MongoDB and `pymongo` to create a database and store data in them. I have a list that I wish to store in a database. And as far as I understand, I would have to use Python dict to do so and it gets stored as an array in the database. Now after storing it, to perform other operations such as plotting, mathematical operations etc. I want to set that array as a variable. But I cannot find a way to do so. Simply setting that array as a list/array variable is good enough. The variable 'results' does not print the array.

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")

db= client['l']
collection=db['data']
x= [1,2,3,4,5]
record = {'_id': 'x', 'values': x}
db.collection.insert_one(record)

results= collection.find({'values':x})
```

Comment: 'db.collection.insert_one(record)'  no this does not raise any error. 'collection.find()' gives pymongo.cursor.Cursor object.

Comment: What does `collection.find_one({"_id":"x"})["values"]` show?

Comment: same thing- pymongo.cursor.Cursor object

Comment: I believe `db.collection.insert_one(record)` is creating/using a collection named `collection` not `data`. Is that what you want?

Comment: no, i simply want the list x from the database (after x has been saved into the database first).

Answer (score 0):

First, i guess your database name is `l` and the collection in that database is `data`. To insert in your collection change your `insert_one` line into something like this :

```
#one way
collection.insert_one(record)

#another way
client['l']['data'].insert_one(record)
```

You can also make some kind of mix using dot notation or array notation.

Then :
`results` is a Cursor instance on which you can iterate to have the documents.

So you can try : `results = [collection.find({'values':x})]`  to have the list of all the document matching your query.

Comment: hi, i am not trying to get the list of documents matching my query. rather i want to get the list x, so that i can use it for other operations.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an `ipython` session showing how you can retrieve your stored `"values"`.

```py
$ ipython
Python 3.10.9 (main, Dec  7 2022, 00:00:00) [GCC 12.2.1 20221121 (Red Hat 12.2.1-4)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.8.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: from pymongo import MongoClient

In [2]: client = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")

In [3]: collection = client["l"]["data"]

In [4]: x= [1,2,3,4,5]
   ...: record = {'_id': 'x', 'values': x}

In [5]: cursor = collection.insert_one(record)

In [6]: print(cursor.acknowledged)
True

In [7]: cursor = collection.find_one({"_id": "x"})

In [8]: print(cursor["values"])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```